# Catch First chance exception in Try and catch block using VC++

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++, com, visual-studio-debugging

In some VC++ code block I am getting following first chance exception -

First-chance exception at 0x77e4bef7 in myapp.EXE: Microsoft C++ exception: ComUtil::ComError at memory location 0x0013ee04..

I can see the above exception in Output window of Visual studio.
How can I catch this exception. I am using Visual studio 2008 for development.

Comment: Are you sure you want to catch it? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/12/438061.aspx

Comment: Actually, in the app there are lot of exceptions of com memory errors appears during debugging, later on due to this app crashes and Visual studio locks. Hence I want to catch these exceptions.

Comment: The problem is, they are already caught - this is what first chance exception means. You could try attaching a profiler, or something like VLD (Visual Leak Detector) to find out the source of the leaks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is just a debugger notification and doesn't otherwise mean anything.  You catch the exception like you normally do, just try/catch.  You want `catch (_com_error& ex)` in this case, it tells you why your COM method call failed.

"First chance" exceptions are useful because you can ask the debugger to stop when the exception is thrown.  Which lets you find out *why* it is thrown.  You use Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown checkbox for C++ exceptions.  Not terribly interesting in the case of _com_error exceptions, you'll just see the auto-generated wrapper you got from the #import directive.  If you don't want to see the noise of the notification then simply right-click the Output window and untick "Exception messages".

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I want to ask is that can I resolve this first chance exception? Do I need to update the VC++ code to resolve it?

Comment: You need to *fix* your code.  You are making a COM method call and it returned a failure HRESULT.  Which is mapped to a _com_error exception so you cannot ignore the failure.  Use the members of the _com_error class to diagnose the reason.  The Error() method returns the HRESULT, the Description() method returns a string that describes the error.  Never skimp on error handling when you use COM.  Methods can and *do* fail.  Usually very early when you first start writing code because the server isn't installed properly.

Comment: Thanks!  On further research in code I found that code fails to open a registry key. Hence an exception is thrown from the code using following code - throw ComUtil::ComError(description, hr);
The first chance exception is thrown on execution of this line. Later on the Com error is picked in the catch block and proper message is logged. I want that this first chance exception gets suppressed while Com error is picked in the catch block as usual. How can I do that? Do I need to remove throw keyword for that?

Comment: Sigh.  Right-click the Output window and untick "Exception messages".

Comment: ok :) thanks a lot! for your help. One more thing, can first chance exceptions locks visual studio and crashes application? Also is it normal that throw keyword show first chance exception?